# Does No-Key the Mushroom King appear in any Exalted 2nd Ed Sourcebooks?

Tags: npc, exalted

No-Key the Mushroom King was originally a canon NPC from 1st edition Exalted in the book *Creatures of the Wild*; notably, he was the only person to have defeated Octavian the Living Tower (a 2nd Circle Demon). No-Key was immortal thanks to a fountain created by a River God and is covered with fungus growths due to prolonged exposure to the 3rd circle spell *Curse of Mists*.

I have not been able to find any reference to him in 2nd edition Exalted. **Does anyone know if he appears in any of the official sourcebooks?** Preferably with updated stats.

Comment: Given that the wiki has no mention of him, I'd guess not. Do you want me to ask on the forum for you?

Comment: @sebsmith if you could ask and report the results here, that'd be fantastic :)

Comment: @brian up here: http://forums.white-wolf.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=45851

Comment: Looks like thats the answer- mentioned in passing but never really revisited as an NPC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No.

As reported [on the Exalted wiki](http://rathess.xi.co.nz/exalted/index.php/Characters:No_Key), this character from Creatures of the Wyld — as of May 31, 2009 — had not been updated to Second Edition.

Comment: That's a very authoritative no.

Comment: I like using headers for one word answers. I think it lends them a certain amount of gravitas.

Comment: So I see.  Are your answers junior-black-holes-in-training then? ;)

Comment: Bolds, /h1s etc, are all quite handy for quick reference. Though Jadasc's H1 is rather... dense :)

Comment: Well, that ends it for certain.